# Can PDTextField set a text color with an alpha value?

Tags: java, pdf, text, pdfbox

I am currently setting the default appearance string to set the text color like this:

`String defaultAppearance = "/Helv 12 Tf 0 0 1 rg";`

`field.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearance);`

I cant seem to find anywhere if there are other options for the formatting string other than rg for RGB or g for black and white.

Is there a way to set the text color to an rgba color, set the text alpha, or documentation on the format of the default appearance string I could look at?

Comment: I've never seen this... In theory one could use an ExtGState resource name in the same way we use a font resource name. However PDFBox itself just looks for font and color when creating the appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for *documentation on the format of the default appearance string*. You can find that (surprise!) in the pdf specification ISO 32000:

> **DA** string *(Required; inheritable)* The default appearance string containing  a sequence of valid page-content graphics  or text state operators that define such properties as the field’s text size and colour.

*(ISO 32000-2, Table  228 — Additional  entries  common  to  all  fields  containing  variable  text)*

And thereafter in more detail,

> The default appearance string (**DA**) contains any graphics state or text state  operators needed to establish the graphics state parameters, such as text size and colour, for displaying the field’s variable text. Only operators that are allowed within text objects shall occur in this string (see "Figure 9  — Graphics objects"). At a minimum, the string shall include a **Tf** (text font)  operator along with its two operands, font and size. The specified font value shall match a resource name in the **Font** entry of the default resource dictionary (referenced from the **DR** entry of the interactive form dictionary;  see "Table 224 — Entries in the interactive form dictionary"). A zero value for size means that the font shall  be auto-sized: its size shall be computed  as an implementation dependent function.
>
> The default appearance string shall contain at most one **Tm** (text matrix)  operator. If this operator is present, the interactive PDF processor shall replace the horizontal and vertical translation components with positioning values it determines to be appropriate, based on the field value, the quadding (**Q**) attribute, and any layout rules it employs. If the default appearance string contains no **Tm** operator, the viewer shall insert one in the appearance stream (with appropriate horizontal and vertical translation components) after the default appearance string and before  the text-positioning and textshowing operators for the variable text.

*(ISO 32000-2 section 12.7.4.3 — Variable text)*

According to that figure 9 the allowed operation classes in a text object are are:

[image: excerpt of figure 9]

Among these the Text Showing and Marked Content operators are not graphics state or text state operators, thus the available operators are:

- *General graphics state* **w, J, j, M, d, ri, i, gs**
- *Color* **CS, cs, SC, SCN, sc, scn, G, g, RG, rg, K, k**
- *Text state* **Tc, Tw, Tz, TL, Tf, Tr, Ts**
- *Text positioning* **Td, TD, Tm, T***

*(ISO 32000-2, Table 50 — Operator categories)*

Obviously I cannot copy the specification of all these operators here.

Of special interest, though, is the general graphics state operator **gs** which allows you to use an use an **ExtGState** resource to set transparency as already proposed by Tilman in a comment to your question.

One word of warning, though, many pdf processors will merely expect a font setting (**Tf**) and a simple color setting (**rg** / **g** / **k**) operation and ignore everything else.